# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (891,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_37:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, kaggle

```
    import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

PREDICTORS = ["Pclass", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare", "Embarked"]
TARGET = ["Survived"]

def load_file(path):
    data = pd.read_csv(path)
    data["Age"] = data["Age"].fillna(data["Age"].mean())
    data["Sex"] = data["Sex"].apply(lambda sex: 1 if sex == "male" else 0)

    data["Embarked"] = data["Embarked"].fillna("S")

    data.loc[data["Embarked"] == "S", "Embarked"] = 0
    data.loc[data["Embarked"] == "C", "Embarked"] = 1
    data.loc[data["Embarked"] == "Q", "Embarked"] = 2

    data["Fare"] = data["Fare"].fillna(data["Fare"].mean())

    return data

train, test = load_file("../input/train.csv"), load_file("../input/test.csv")
train.head()
test.head()

train_x_data = train.loc[:, ["Pclass", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare", "Embarked"]]
print(train_x_data.head())

test_x_data = test.loc[:, ["Pclass", "Sex", "Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare", "Embarked"]]
print(test_x_data.head())

train_y_data = train.loc[:, "Survived"]
print(train_y_data.head())

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 7])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7, 1]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='bias')

hypothesis = tf.matmul(X, W) + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-5)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for step in range(2001):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={X:train_x_data, Y:train_y_data})
```

hello guys
I'm a beginner in kaggle

And trying 'titanic tutorial' in this site (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)

My problem is the last code of the source (sess.run(train, feed_dict={X:train_x_data, Y:train_y_data})) <- this part!

Computer error says I have problem in feed_dict on using shape
I have used [None, 7] shape I you can see in the source and I don't get the problem.

Can someone help me solve the problem??

Comment: I'll write error code here.

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (891,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_37:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Comment: On a quick glance, it would seem you need to transpose your Y data - instead of feeding the tensor samples of the 7 features, you're feeding it 7 samples, each representing the values of the feature among all passengers.

Comment: thank you @jkm I solve the problem it was not about transposing Y data. Y data was correct. It was the shape having problem. The shape was (891,) <- non defined. So I made another dataFrame and shape changed to (891,1). And the problem was solved! Anyway Thank you for the answer